# Delete UITableViewCell that has IBOutlets in it

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, xcode8

Should be simple, but I forgot. DO I need to dequeue the cell in the delete method as well as cellForRowAt?

Heres the Cell :

```
class Row : UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var rating: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var address: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var status: UILabel!
```

}

Heres the delete method:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.row)

    if (editingStyle == .delete) {

        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

How would I add the variables to get deleted? I know I can't simple type for example :

```
name.remove(at: indexPath ) <-- or something like that. whats the cleanest method? Thanks
```

Comment: Stream can you explain more about your question? What is name over here ?

Comment: You have to remove the object from dataSource array first, then use `deleteRows`

Answer (score 0):

If you mean get the row you delete.

`let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath)`

Use this **BEFORE** you delete the row.

And you must remove data from data source before you delete the row. In that case, you need `dataArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)`

Comment: If the IBOutlets are connected to CoreData...I can just do a data delete rather than delete each single variable correct? Like above.